# Firebase Cloud Function scheduled function not running

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm attempting my first *scheduled* cloud function. To test, I'm trying to run it every 1 minute and will increase later.

I've deployed it but haven't yet seen it run via the Firebase Logs.

Here's what I've deployed:

```
const fetchMovies = require('./data/fetchMovies');
exports.fetchMovies = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 1 minute').onRun((context) => {
  console.log("Running, with this context:", context)
  fetchMovies.handler(db);
});
```

Any idea what may be incorrect here?

Comment: If a deployment isn't working the way you expect and there are no clear errors, contact Firebase support for troubleshooting.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: It isn't clear that 'minute' is a valid value in the schedule -- perhaps try 'minutes' or 'mins', per https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref

Comment: Seems minute isn't valid. Working with minutes, thank you! @DougStevenson will do. Didn't know support existed for non-account issues. What's the typical turnaround time for that support channel?

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions#write_a_scheduled_function)

A 5 minute example...

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun((context) => {
  console.log('This will be run every 5 minutes!');
  return null;
});
```

> Both Unix Crontab and AppEngine syntax are supported by Google Cloud
> Scheduler.

```
exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions.pubsub.schedule('5 11 * * *')
  .timeZone('America/New_York') // Users can choose timezone - default is America/Los_Angeles
  .onRun((context) => {
  console.log('This will be run every day at 11:05 AM Eastern!');
  return null;
});
```

Answer (score -2):

To trigger a function every minute use the string '* * * * *'. Thats every minute in unix. Don't forget that every * must separated from each other with a space

Like:

```
const fetchMovies = require('./data/fetchMovies');

exports.fetchMovies = functions.pubsub.schedule('* * * * *').onRun((context) => {
  console.log("Running, with this context:", context)
  fetchMovies.handler(db);
});
```